# vue-cli and strange politycy something. How disable Content Security Policy and why it occure

Tags: sass, content-security-policy, vue-cli

I try to set vue-cli with scss, but everythin what I found is one huge mess. I added scss-loader, css-loader and style-loader. I created some style.scss and import it in my main.js file:

webpack.base.conf:

```
 ...
 module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
         use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
      ],
    },
 ...
```

and in main.js just

```
 import './style.scss';
```

Nothing special, but then I got an error:

> Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so
>   'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I never ever before got something like that. I tried add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;**script-src 'self' http://onlineerp.solution.quebec 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';** ">
```

as some solutions say, but it give me nothing. What strange, It occured after I add this few loaders. So my guestions:
1. what it is (Content Security Policy), and why it occure, expecially why it occure after I add css-loader, style-loader and scss-loader
2. what I'm doing wrong? I really don't know what I doing wrond and how to fix it
3. I so, that I can no use Content Security Policy, but how to disable it?

Comment: :-( Noone help?